# Cloud Composer Scheduler Restarting Errors

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I just updated my Cloud Composer environment to `composer-1.10.3-airflow-1.10.6` and started periodically seeing the yellow warning box in the web ui that the scheduler hasn't been responding. Looking in the logs for `airflow-scheduler` I'm seeing the errors below, and it appears to be happening after composer mounts a bucket with FUSE.

[image: scheduler error]

I'm also seeing a large number of restarts happening, which I'm guessing is being caused by the errors above.

[image: scheduler restarts]

Has anyone else run into this or know what would be causing this error/how to fix?

Comment: Do you observe the issues only with `airflow-scheduler`, how about the other components?

Comment: Yes, only the scheduler. The other nodes have no restarts. It's very strange, I haven't been able to uncover the root cause.

Comment: Can you check memory and CPU utilization on GKE nodes and particularly where affected `airflow-scheduler` is residing? Perhaps Airflow GKE cluster has to be investigated more in detail in order to came up with conclusion.